# Failing a controlling grapple check, what actions remain?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, actions, grapple

When you are grappling a creature, and you make the 2nd round check to maintain the grapple, and fail. What actions do you have left? Because if you succeed you have the ability to make a attack which suggests a standard action remains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a move action.  The [grappling rules state](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Grapple) (emphasis mine),

> Once you are grappling an opponent, a successful check allows you to continue grappling the foe, and also allows you to perform one of the following actions (as *part of the standard action spent to maintain the grapple*).